# Django raw_id_fields read_only permission

Tags: python, django

I have this Django project that I'm working on, which won't allow users to select an entry (`User` entries) on the `raw_id_fields` popup, if they don't have change permissions (which they can't have at all). That's really weird cause that doesn't happen with the select tag list if I remove the `raw_id_fields` attribute on my `ModelForm` class at `admins.py`.

How can this permission behavior be consistent if it changes according to a different interface setting? I mean, user only have permission to select users on the form if they are displayed as a select tag. It seems to me that it's a big consistency failure with the way Django permissions was designed, which, in my opinion, should have native `can_view` permission, in addition to `can_|add, change, delete`.

While googling around I found a few topics discussing this matter, but all of them end up with some really painful solutions that don't seem straightforward to me. I wonder if something so simple could have a straightforward solution that won't require lots of workarounds.

Here is an example that looks like my actual code:

#### models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

#### admins.py

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ['manager',]
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, this is really weird. Thats why I've opted to "extend" the django admin to my specific requirements sometimes.

The easiest way to meet this goal is by overriding the [has_change_permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) of the referenced ModelAdmin

As you have the request object as an argument of the method, you can evaluate:

- if the request comes from a raw_id_field or not
- if the user has permissions to see that models or not
- any other constraint you have

A simple prototype for the method:

```
def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj is None and '_popup' in request.GET:
        return True

    return super(MyAdmin, self).has_change_permission(request, obj)
```

Comment: That worked! I've overridden the has_change_permission of the user model on my admin. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just take into account that this is the simplest way to do that, and because of that, isn't secure at all because any user can get access to your changelist by just adding _pop in the querystring.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the paramenter for my version of Django (1.7.4) is '_popup', not '_pop'. Don't know about other versions.

Comment: Maybe it was my fault, I didn't test it when I wrote the answer.

Comment: In my use case there is no problem if users can access the changelist as they won't be able modify or add one anyway.